# c# Accessing an Object / Object Method when the Object is stored in a linked list

Tags: c#, hash, linked-list, blockchain

This application is supposed to be a sort of demo of how blockchain works. I have a block chain class and a block class and the program class is main. In the blockchain class I am creating an initial block called the gensis block in the createGenesisBlock() method. In the constructor of my blockchain class I am calling the createGenesisBlock() method and inserting the object into my linked-list which is called chain. The problem I have is when the object is added to the linked-list in my blockchain class I cannot access the object or the methods. What I am trying to accomplish is to use my getLatestBlock() method in the blockchain class to retrieve the value of hash of the last object that was put into chain. Thus being able to call my addBlock method in blockchain setting the value of previousHash equal to the value of hash of the object in the linked-list

```
namespace BlockChainProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Blockchain blockChain = new Blockchain();
            blockChain.addBlock();
            blockChain.display();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

namespace BlockChainProject
{

    class Block
    {
        private int index;
        private string timeStamp;
        private string data;
        private string previousHash;
        private string hash;


        public Block(int index, string timeStamp, string data, string previousHash) {
            this.index = index;
            this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
            this.data = data;
            this.previousHash = previousHash;
            this.hash = this.calculateHash();
        }

        public string calculateHash() {
            SHA256Managed hashString = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] dataArray = hashString.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString() + previousHash + timeStamp + data));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte x in dataArray)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", x);
            }

            string hashed = stringBuilder.ToString();
            return hashed;
        }

        public string getHash() {
            return hash;
        }
    }

}

namespace BlockChainProject
{
    class Blockchain
    {
        LinkedList<object> chain;
        private int index = 0;
        private string time = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        public Blockchain(){
            chain = new LinkedList<object>();
            chain.AddLast(createGenesisBlock());
        }

        private object createGenesisBlock() {
            index++;
            return new Block(index, time, "Genesis Block", "0"); ;
        }

        public object getLatestBlock() {
            return chain.Last.Value;
        }

        public void addBlock() {
            string data = Console.ReadLine();
            //string previousHash = <The hash of linked lists last object here>;
            chain.AddLast(new Block(index, time, data, previousHash));
            index++;

        }

        public void display() {
            foreach (var item in chain)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly ran your code and I think that I have figured out your problem. You need to do a find and replace on "object" and replace it with "Block" or alternatively you need to cast the objects that are being returned from the getLast function to "Block".

An example of the changes will look like so:

```
LinkedList<Block> chain;
```

...

```
public Block getLatestBlock() {
    return chain.Last.Value;
}
```

This is some examples of the changes to be made to the Blockchain class there may be others but I can't remember.

Now when you call the display function you have access to the functions and methods of each of the Block class instances in the linked list, like so:

```
public void display()
{
    foreach (var item in chain)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.getHash());
    }
}
```

This will now print a list of the hashes provided that you changed all of the returns, types and instances where you used object in the linked list, to Block.

The reason for this is if you create a linkedlist of generic "object"s then at compile time C# has no idea what might be in the linked lists. It could be Blocks or it could be Bananas, so it doesn't know what functions and methods each object will have available to call. So to let C# know we have to either cast it using "as Block" after we get the item from the list or in your case just set the type of all values in the linked like to "Block" as by the looks of your program you aren't going to have generic entries to the list.

Hopefully this answers your question. If not let me know.

Comment: Yes that answers my question thank you very much I was not aware I could tell the linked list to be of the type Block your explanation was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

When you specify your chain as

```
LinkedList<object> chain
```

You are telling the compiler that the chain variable is a linked list that contains an object class, or any descendent of object.

The following code is therefore legal by your definition of chain

```
chain.Add("Hi there!");
chain.Add(new Dictionary<int, decimal>());
chain.Add(new Giraffe());
chain.Add(42);
```

You cannot call `calculateHash()` because unfortunately, our string,  Dictionary, Giraffe and int classes wouldn't know what to do with such a method call.

Instead, chain should be declared as

```
LinkedList<Block> chain;
```

This means that chain can only contain elements that are of type Block (or a descendent class of Block).

Whilst the calls to these methods are not shown in code, you will need to then change the `createGenesisBlock()` and `getLatestBlock()` methods to return Block rather than object, because you are not allowed to add just any object to your linked list anymore, it must be a Block.

Comment: both of your answers really cleared this up for me thank you I didn't know I could tell linked list that it can take block I just assumed object would be what I needed to use much appreciated